# Android app crashes when it load ads on Firestick Device

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

I am trying to make my android app compatible with Firestick device . Unfortunately after making few tests I realised that it crashes when It tries to load ads on the app , no matter if its a banner or interstitial .

The banner & the interstitial codes are linked with my server so whenever I disable them the app works good

I don't know how can I fix that because on my android device it works good , does firestick prohibite google play ads ?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace if app crashes.

Comment: @Mohsen the problem is that I don't have any stacktrace , as I just send the apk to a friend of mine and he test it on his device . he said that the app just crashes and no error appeares .. but after making few changes I realised the it comes from the google ads codes

Comment: Are you using Android Studio to make the app? I said stacktrace because we have no idea what's going on so, there would be some logs, crash reports or anything helpful about the app.

Comment: yes Im using android studio , I'll try to integrate an sdk to get the crash reports and I'll let you know  thanks for your help